# Nested Where on 1-to-many in LINQ2Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm using EF4. Having 2 entities:
Person { Name }
Hobbys { Person.Name, IsCoolHobby }
1 Person can have several hobbys.

I now have

```
IQueryable<Person> p;
p = container.PersonSet.Include("Hobbys").AsQueryable();
p = p.Where(x => x ?????);
List<Person> tmp = p.ToList();
```

How can i return only those Persons who have cool hobbys (IsCoolHobby == true)? I tried join but i was not able to load them into the list (select can only return Person, Hobby or new Type - but how to map them to entity objects again?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i return only those Persons who have cool hobbys (IsCoolHobby
>   == true)?

```
List<Person> tmp = container.PersonSet.Include("Hobbys")
    .Where(p => p.Hobbys.Any(h => h.IsCoolHobby))
    .ToList();
```

This will load the people who have at least one cool hobby but the `Hobbys` collection for those people will always contain *all* hobbys, also the uncool hobbys.

**Edit**

Unfortunately filtering and sorting children during eager loading (`Include`) is currently not supported. There is a [request on the EF feature suggestion page for this feature](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method). The request has status "Under review", so there is a little hope that it might get implemented in the future. (Probably *far* future: At least the first docs about EF 5 (beta) on MSDN say explicitly that eager loading with filtering/sorting is still not implemented.)

For now there are only two workarounds. The first is to use a projection:

```
var projectedData = container.PersonSet
    .Where(p => p.Hobbys.Any(h => h.IsCoolHobby))
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Person = p,
        CoolHobbys = p.Hobbys.Where(h => h.IsCoolHobby)
    })
    .ToList();
```

The result is a collection of anonymous objects which contain a user who has cool hobbys and a collection of those cool hobbys. If you don't disable change tracking (by using the `NoTracking` option for the query) the person's hobbys collection should be filled with the result automatically.

The second option is to use "explicit" loading with `CreateSourceQuery`:

```
List<Person> tmp = container.PersonSet
    .Where(p => p.Hobbys.Any(h => h.IsCoolHobby))
    .ToList();
foreach (var person in tmp)
{
    person.Hobbys.Attach(person.Hobbys.CreateSourceQuery()
        .Where(h => h.IsCoolHobby).ToList());
}
```

Two things to note here:

- `CreateSourceQuery` is only available on `EntityCollection`s, i.e. if you are using `EntityObject` derived entities. It's not available for POCO entities in EF 4.0. (EF >= 4.1/`DbContext` has the option for explicit loading also for POCOs -> `Query()` method.)
- The above code represents 1+N roundtrips to the database: The first for the person collection without the hobbys and then one additional query per person to load the cool hobbys.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to load all Persons and only the cool hobbys (sorry didnt specified that proper)
Assume the Person has at least 1 hobby